# How can i get the value from collection in php

Tags: php, mysql, key

I have data store in the below format

```
 [{"id":"927","store_id":"63","cover":"Banana.png","name":"Organic Banana / Kela / Keli"}]
```

I need to fetch the name and all the key value pairs. but don't know how to do it in Core PHP. If anyone helps it would be greate. Thanks :)

Comment: This looks like standard `JSON` so you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Once you use `json_decode` you can loop with `foreach`

Comment: Yes, @AndreaOlivato I get my answer thanks, buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$json = '[{"id":"927","store_id":"63","cover":"Banana.png","name":"Organic Banana / Kela / Keli"}]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($json_decoded as $product){
    echo($product['name']);
    // get others similarly
}
```